# ManagedObject has nil context after save

Tags: ios, core-data

This is on a background thread. It's a private concurrency type context and it's performed within context performBlock. I'm doing it right, at least I think I am.

I'm not a beginner to core data, however I could be missing something obvious - as I've been staring at this a while.

Here is the code:

```
FFXCollection *backgroundCollection = (FFXCollection *) [context objectWithID:collectionID];

//At this point backgroundCollection.managedObjectContext is the same as context

NSError *error = nil;
[context save:&error];
NSLog(@"error %@", error); //Note that there is no error here

if (!backgroundCollection.managedObjectContext) {
DLog(@"why not?"); //At this point the managedObjectContext is nil!!!
}
```

Why is the managedObjectContext becoming nil inside the managed object?

The example is contrived, but demonstrates my problem. In my actually code, a save occurs and then i'm trying to set up a relationship. Then when another save occurs I get a validation error because of the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use existingObjectWithID instead.

> existingObjectWithID:error: Returns the object for the specified ID.
>
> - (NSManagedObject *)existingObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID error:(NSError **)error Parameters objectID The object ID for the requested object. error If there is a problem in retrieving
>     the object specified by objectID, upon return contains an error that
>     describes the problem. Return Value The object specified by objectID.
>     If the object cannot be fetched, or does not exist, or cannot be
>     faulted, it returns nil.
>
> Discussion
>   **If there is a managed object with the given ID already registered in the context, that object is returned directly; otherwise the
>   corresponding object is faulted into the context.**
>
> This method might perform I/O if the data is uncached.
>
> **Unlike objectWithID:, this method never returns a fault**.
>
> Availability Available in OS X v10.6 and later. See Also –
>   objectWithID: – objectRegisteredForID: Declared In
>   NSManagedObjectContext.h

Comment: If you ignore the bit i said about the relationship and just read the code above, then all i'm doing is loading an object, saving the context and then it's context is nil. There is no relationship in this example code.

Comment: You are loading it from an ID? Where are you getting that ID? Try fetching the object first then saving it. It's possible the id is changing.

Comment: Cool that works!... now I need to figure out why. objectWithID is not throwing an exception. They both return an object. The FFXCollection is loaded on the main thread in the main context, it passes it's objectID to a newly created background context to load data from the network into it. Once the data has loaded, they are associated with the FFXCollection, and it return back to the main thread to refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the docs, however I have read this and it's not any clearer. Both methods return the object, however after an immediate save of the background context, using objectWithID breaks the objects relationship to the context. Whereas existingObjectWithID doesn't. I need to know the underlying reason behind this. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Are faulted objects removed from the context after a save?

Comment: Take a look at NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification and see what happens to that object. It may clear things up. If I had to guess, firing the existingObjectWithID is actually faulting a new object into the context. I tend to always stay away from accessing CoreData objects  with an ID and always fetch the object when I need it or create a property to hold the object since temp IDs change after saving.

Comment: It seems you only get a permanent object ID once it's saved to a persistent store. Thanks, you've helped a lot - I'm going to look into this further to get a thorough understanding.

Comment: I feel your pain. I went through the exact same thing when dealing with IDs and then there's data migration... which can also change IDs so if you store an ID for a long period of time it will eventually change. The best thing is to store your own unique ID (timestamp, etc.) and fetch based on that. Glad it helped!